# How to display a dictionary across multiple pages in Flask?

Tags: python, dictionary, flask, pagination

There are more than 1000 items in my database and I want to display these products on my website. These items are fetched as a dictionary. I searched for this problem on StackOverflow. I found something but the items were fetched as a list.

```py
@app.route("/",methods = ["GET","POST"])
def index():
    if request.method == "GET":
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
        sorgu = "SELECT * from all_products"
        result = cursor.execute(sorgu)
        if result > 0:
            products = cursor.fetchall()
            totalproducts = len(products)
            totalproductsinpage = countproductsall(products)
            success = int((totalproducts - totalproductsinpage )* 100 / totalproducts)
            return render_template("index.html",products = products,totalproducts = totalproducts,totalproductsinpage = totalproductsinpage,success = success)
        else:
            flash("Ürün bulunamadı!","warning")
            return render_template("index.html")
```

Comment: Btw, there is a table in index.html for products

Comment: *These items are fetched as a dictionary* - wrong, they are fetched as a list of dicts , as expected

Comment: Please paste your index.html template file. I'm guessing you're asking for a framework that will easily do pagination for you with large resultset? Might be better to look in the javascript area.